# How to continue timer after using clearInterval( );

Tags: javascript, jquery, clearinterval

I have the following function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#p').click(function() {
        $('#s1').hide();
        gameStart(); <-starts timer
        $('#s2').show();
    });

    $('.b4').click(function() {
        clearInterval(tI); <-stops the time
    });
    $('#r').click(function() {
        tI = setInterval("setTimer()", 1000); <-not working, should continue the timer again
    });
});
```

When the div `#p` is clicked it will start a game with a timer, this all works. Now if I click the div `.b4` it will stop/pauze the timer, this also works. The problem is to start the timer again, continuing from where it was stopped.

I've tried `tI = setInterval("setTimer()", 1000);` when clicking the div `#r` but the problem with this is that is will start the timer, but it will not continue from the time it was stopped. It will continue, but from the time where it should be if it wasn't stopped/pauzed.

SO how can I fix this? I want to pause the time (think I have this part right) and then continue it again when clicking `#r`

This is how my timer function is build:

```
function gameStart() {
    setBlocks();
    tM = $('#a1 div.tm');
    hS = $('#a1 div.hs');
    oT = new Date();
    tI = setInterval("setTimer()", 1000);
    setHs();
    $('.ht').click(hint);
    $('.b3').click(reset);
}


//Set timer
function setTimer() {
    var n = new Date();
    tM.text(getTimeText(n.getTime() - oT.getTime()));
}

//Build timer
function getTimeText(v) {
    var vH = Math.floor(v / 3600000);
    var vM = Math.floor((v - (vH * 3600000)) / 60000);
    var vS = Math.floor((v - (vH * 3600000) - (vM * 60000)) / 1000);
    return set2Digit(vH) + ':' + set2Digit(vM) + ':' + set2Digit(vS);
}

function set2Digit(ov) {
    var os = '0' + ov;
    return os.substr(os.length - 2, 2);
}
```

--EDIT--

With this html I get the time to show: `<div class="tm">00:00:00</div>`

--EDIT2--
Okay created a new function. It grabs the paused time, so from this point the time should continue:

```
$('#r').click(function() {
        $('#s1').hide();
        tI = setInterval("continueTimer()", 1000); //NEW
        $('#s2').show();
    });

//Test
function continueTimer() {
    divObj = document.getElementById("tm");
    tM.text(divObj.innerText);
}
```

At the moment, the time pauses but doesn't continue when this function is fired... So how do I start the timer from this point? I think I am close

Comment: Set `oT = new Date()` when `#r` is clicked to update the offset from the game start time to the resume time.

Comment: This will reset the time to 0 again, instead of continuing from the point it stopped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because in `setTimer` method you are creating a `new Date` object. So everytime this method executes it will take the current time. If you want to continue form where the timer was stopped instead of creating  `new Date` object everytime, maintain the start date when the timer starts in a variable and then use that variable inside `setTimer` method.

Modify the below method and add a global variable.

```
var initialTime;
function setTimer() {
    tM.text(getTimeText(initialTime.getTime() - oT.getTime()));
    initialTime.setMilliseconds(1000);
}

function gameStart() {
    setBlocks();
    tM = $('#a1 div.tm');
    hS = $('#a1 div.hs');
    oT = new Date();
    initialTime = new Date();
    setTimer();
    tI = setInterval("setTimer()", 1000);
    setHs();
    $('.ht').click(hint);
    $('.b3').click(reset);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work, the downside is that at gamestart the timer will start with a delay. Normally it would start immediately, but now I has a 1 a 2 sec delay before the time starts (please note, this happens at game start so not after pausing it, that works great). Any idea why this delay is in there now?

Comment: Thanks for the effort, really appreciate it, it is faster but still there is a 1 sec delay from the original gameStart

Comment: Can't I just use the original code and use the current time when paused with a document.getElementById?

Comment: You can do that but you have to create a date object using that.

Comment: Please see my edit2 in my topic. I feel I am close but the timer doesn't start counting

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below,

```
$('#r').click(function() {
    oT = new Date(); //this will move the offset date to the resume time..
    tI = setInterval(setTimer, 1000);
});
```

Comment: never use a string inside of a setInterval. `setInterval(setTimer, 1000)`

Comment: This will reset the time to 0 again, instead of continuing from the point it stopped